Custom Node Buttons Handles Not Updating or Reordering Properly
I'm building a flow editor using React Flow and Framer Motion. I'm facing an issue when adding or reordering buttons within custom nodes.
Each custom node has an array of buttons.by clicking add button (inside node) I can add another button. and each button has a Handle. I'm using Reorder.Group from Framer Motion to handle the reordering of buttons, but when I reorder buttons, buttons get reordered, but when I click handle of button 1, edge start from its previous position.
I am using useUpdateNodeInternals to notify React Flow of internal node updates, but something seems off. for reordering buttons, I'm using Reorder.Group from shadcn.
in below picture, before reordering list, when I click Handle of button 1, edge starts from correct position. (no issues here)

in below picture, after reordering, when I click Handle of Button 3, edge starts from its previous position, (now button 1 is there)

Here is the relevant code for the custom node and the React Flow integration:
custom node, genericTemplateNode.tsx
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { Handle, Position, useUpdateNodeInternals } from "@xyflow/react";
import { Reorder } from "framer-motion";
import ActionButton from "../ui/genericTemplateUtils/actionButtons";
import { Button } from "./Interface/NodesInterface";

const GenericTemplateNode = ({ id, data }: { id: string, data: { setNodes: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Node[]>>, buttons: Button[] } }) => {
  const [idbutton, setIdbutton] = useState<number>(1);
  const updateNodeInternals = useUpdateNodeInternals();

  // Function to update buttons
  const updateButtons = useCallback((_buttons: Button[]) => {
    data.setNodes((nds) =>
      nds.map((node) => {
        if (node.id === id) {
          return {
            ...node,
            data: { ...node.data, buttons: _buttons }
          };
        }
        return node;
      })
    );
    updateNodeInternals(id); // Notify React Flow of changes
  }, [id, data.setNodes]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Reorder.Group
        axis="y"
        values={data.buttons}
        onReorder={(newButtons) => updateButtons(newButtons)}
      >
        {data.buttons.map((button) => (
          <ActionButton key={button.id} button={button} />
        ))}
      </Reorder.Group>
      <Handle position={Position.Left} type="target" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GenericTemplateNode;


react-flow .tsx
Im passing setNode in data of node.
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { ReactFlow, applyNodeChanges, Node } from "@xyflow/react";
import GenericTemplateNode from "@/components/GenericTemplateNode";

const initialNodes: Node[] = [];

export default function FlowBuilder() {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState<Node[]>(initialNodes);

  const addNode = () => {
    const newNode = {
      id: (nodes.length + 1).toString(),
      type: 'genericTemplate',
      position: { x: Math.random() * 250, y: Math.random() * 250 },
      data: { **setNodes**, buttons: [] },
    };
    setNodes((nds) => [...nds, newNode]);
  };

  const onNodesChange = useCallback(
    (changes) => setNodes((nds) => applyNodeChanges(changes, nds)),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={addNode}>Add Node</button>
      <ReactFlow nodes={nodes} onNodesChange={onNodesChange} nodeTypes={{ genericTemplate: GenericTemplateNode }} />
    </div>
  );
}


issue resolved, when I set timeout on updateNodeInternals.
 // let ui re-render and then update handles position, without this, Handle position will have issue
   setTimeout(() => {
     updateNodeInternals(id)
   }, 500);

